# Why does the access_token expire when I execute this code?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Every time I execute this code, it does not work and the access_token expires.

```
FB.api('user.ID_post.ID/likes?access_token=######', 'post', function(response) {console.log(response); });
```

Basically what I want to do here is, like a post using a user's access_token, but the token gets expired on every execution.

Why is this happening? Why is it not working? Is there any other way to do the same thing using a user's access_token? how would that be done? can anybody show/provide me that piece of code to do this?

All I want to do is, like post using a user's access token via JS SDK(if there's no way with JS SKD, PHP SDK wouldn't be problem too)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research I found out that we can use `access_token=xxxx` with Javascript SDK as it is not safe.

Alternatively, Using PHP SDK to set access token and then calling API to do something works fine.